# Input text field is getting blank after onchnage event

Tags: javascript, callback, onchange

I have an input like below

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Select your arrival date..."
                                                    class="input__input datePickerBar__input " id="inpCalendarDate" onchange="dateFunction(event);false"/>
```

and my entered input is getting lost after the event change. I tried like below

```js
function dateFunction(event){


var bla=$("#inpCalendarDate").val();
    console.log(bla);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    $("#inpCalendarDate").val("test");
}
```

But my  inpCalendarDate is getting blank. Please help

Comment: What's the point of the `;false`, the `event.preventDefault();` and the `return false;`?

Answer (score 0):

After `return` statement the code is unreachable, so it is not updating the input box. Either remove return statement or add it as last line of the function

```js
function dateFunction(event) {
  var bla = $("#inpCalendarDate").val();
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#inpCalendarDate").val("test");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Select your arrival date..." class="input__input datePickerBar__input " id="inpCalendarDate" onchange="dateFunction(event)" />
```